# Doctrine 2: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WHEN, got Some\Namespace\Class

Tags: symfony2, symfony, doctrine2, doctrine

Класс:

```
<?php

namespace KrasTFOMSWSBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KrasTFOMSWSBundle\Entity\Repository\MappedTreatmentCaseRepository",readOnly=true)
 * @ORM\Table(name="REGSTWEB.WS_CALC_KSG")
 */
class MappedTreatmentCase
{
    /**
     * @var string Идентификатор сеанса, в который происходит расчет
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",name="SESSION_ID")
     */
    protected $sessionId;
    /**
     * @var string Идентификатор случая лечения
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",name="CASE_ID")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var MappedTreatmentCaseUnit[] Переводы между отделениями
     */
    protected $items;
    /**
     * @var integer Стоимость лечения
     */
    protected $price;
    /**
     * @param MappedTreatmentCaseUnit[] $items
     */
    public function setItems(array $items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }
    /**
     * @param int $price
     */
    public function setPrice(int $price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCaseId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
<?php

namespace KrasTFOMSWSBundle\Entity\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Class MappedTreatmentCaseRepository
 * @package KrasTFOMSWSBundle\Entity\Repository
 */
class MappedTreatmentCaseRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Поиск по идентификатору сессии
     *
     * @param string $sessionId
     * @return array
     */
    public function findBySessionId(string $sessionId)
    {
        return  $this->createQueryBuilder('case')
        ->select('case')
        ->where('case.sessionId = :sessionId')
        ->setParameter('sessionId', $sessionId)
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Вызов метода репозитория:

```
//Извлечение результата
$result = $this->mappedTreatmentCaseRepository->findBySessionId($sessionId);
```

В результате:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 26: Error: Expected
>   Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WHEN, got
>   'KrasTFOMSWSBundle\Entity\MappedTreatmentCase'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать:

```
$result = $this->mappedTreatmentCaseRepository->findOneBy(['sessionId' => $sessionId]);
```

Comment: Постарайтесь давать более развернутые ответы